# Using Increment and Decrement Operators in Initialisation, Condition and Updation in For Loop

Tags: c, for-loop, decrement

Today I had a test on C at my university and one of the questions asked to give the output for this block of code:

```
int a=9;

    for(a--;a--;a--)

        printf("%d\n",a);
```

I thought this would create an infinite loop but on checking it gave

```
7

5

3

1
```

as output. Why did it not create an infinite loop? What's going on in this program?

Comment: Why would you expect that to give an infinite loop?

Comment: Once `a` decrements to 0, the loop exits

Comment: I thought it would've gone below 1 covering all negative values.

Comment: Well, for even initial value of `a` it will give an infinite loop/UB. But here it is odd.

Comment: @EugeneSh. , I don't get it.

Comment: What don't you get? The `a` is decrementing twice between each check. So for even `a` the check will miss the moment it is zero, so the loop condition is always true. With odd `a` the check will catch the moment it is zero and the loop will terminate. Rewrite this loop as an equivalent `while` loop for better understanding.

Comment: @EugeneSh. took me some time but I finally got it. Thanks. The answers helped as well!

Answer (score 4):

If you separate the post-decrement into separate statements this is the equivalent code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
    
int main(void) {
    int a = 9;
    a--;
    while(a) {
        a--;
        printf("%d\n", a);
        a--;
    }
    return;
}
```

Program output:

```
7
5
3
1
```

This won't stop when `a` is even, unless the condition is changed to

```
while(a > 0)
```

Comment: Surely it should be `while(a--) {`, not `while(a) { a--;`? Here, it doesn't matter, but if, say, `--a` was used instead, this would behave differently right?

Comment: @Lecdi the point was to *separate* the post-decrement to clarify what is happening. It was `a--` in the question. Here I use `a` and then apply the decrement `a--` as a separate instruction. And yes, predecrement would be a different question.

Answer (score 2):

Labeling the parts of the `for` statement:

`for(a--1; a--2; a--3)
    printf("%d\n",a);`

it is executed:

- `a` is initially 9.
- `a--1` is evaluated and ignored. This changes `a` to 8.
- `a--2` is evaluated and tested. This changes `a` to 7 and evaluates as 8. Since 8 is non-zero, the `for` execution continues.
- `printf("%d\n",a);` is evaluated. This prints 7.
- `a--3` is evaluated and ignored. This changes `a` to 6.
- `a--2` is evaluated and tested. This changes `a` to 5 and evaluates as 6. Since 6 is non-zero, the `for` execution continues.
- `printf("%d\n",a);` is evaluated. This prints 5.
- `a--3` is evaluated and ignored. This changes `a` to 4.
- `a--2` is evaluated and tested. This changes `a` to 3 and evaluates as 4. Since 4 is non-zero, the `for` execution continues.
- `printf("%d\n",a);` is evaluated. This prints 3.
- `a--3` is evaluated and ignored. This changes `a` to 2.
- `a--2` is evaluated and tested. This changes `a` to 1 and evaluates as 2. Since 2 is non-zero, the `for` execution continues.
- `printf("%d\n",a);` is evaluated. This prints 1.
- `a--3` is evaluated and ignored. This changes `a` to 0.
- `a--2` is evaluated and tested. This changes `a` to −1 and evaluates as 0. Since 0 is zero, the `for` execution ends.

Comment: Thank you this helped. Though I got what was happening I missed the part where the condition becomes 0 ultimately terminating the `for` loop. So I thought this would create an infinite loop.